# Qual a diferença entre os operadores == e === em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operadores

Estou com o seguinte código em JavaScript:

```javascript
var x = 0;

if (x === false) {
  // não acessa
}

if (x == false) {
  // acessa
}
```

Por que a expressão com o operador `==` retorna `true` e com o operador `===` retorna `false`?

Qual é a diferença entre os dois operadores?

Comment: Note que um modo elegante (ao meu ver) de escrever código assim é `if (!x) { /* acessa */ }`

Comment: @CamiloMartin Sim, mas `!x` dá true para alguns valores que `x === false` daria false, como `x = 0`.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

O operador `==` compara por "resultado" digamos assim, ou seja como JavaScript não é fortemente tipado ele converte o que você tá querendo comparar e verifica ou seja:

```js
if (true == 'true')  // aqui vai dar true
if (true == '1')     // aqui vai dar true
if (true == true)    // aqui vai dar true
if (true === 'true') // aqui vai dar false
if (true === '1')    // aqui vai dar false
if (true === true)   // aqui vai dar true
```

O operador `===` ele compara o valor e o tipo, então só vai ser `true` se for exatamente igual (valor e tipo).

---

**Complemento da resposta:**

1. Veja [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) do StackOverflow em Inglês que contém alguns exemplos adicionais.
2. Acho que a explicação ficou meio deficiente, seguinte quando a linguagem não é tipada ele não compara pelo tipo e sim pelo valor, ou seja 15 é a mesma coisa que "15" quando a linguagem não é tipada.

   Mas quando você usa o `===` você força o código a comparar o tipo também, recomendo a leitura desse artigo na [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) para melhor entendimento.

Comment: ``NaN === NaN //false`` <3 JS

Comment: `NaN === NaN` retornar `false` não é uma esquisitisse do JavaScript: É algo esperado, e inclusive especificado pelo padrão IEEE 754 que define números ponto flutuantes. `Float::NAN == Float::NAN` (Ruby) e `float("NaN") == float("NaN")` (Python) também retornam `false`.

Comment: É inclusive uma forma de detectar o NaN, sem usar o isNaN(x): comparar uma variável com ela mesma.

Comment: A lógica é a mesma para !== e !=, correto?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo não não é, !== vai comparar por tipo e valor e != só por valor. Ou seja 1 !== '1' // true e 1 != '1' //false

Answer (score 52):

Segundo a especificação do [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9), o triplo `===` significa "igualdade estrita", ou seja, somente retorna `true` se os operandos forem do mesmo tipo e valor.

Para ser mais exato, o algoritmo, numa comparação `x === y` é:

```js
Se Type(x) é diferente de Type(y), retorna false.
Se Type(x) é Undefined, retorna true.
Se Type(x) é Null, retorna true.
Se Type(x) é Number, então
    Se x é NaN, retorna false.
    Se y é NaN, retorna false.
    Se x é do mesmo valor numérico que y, retorna true.
    Se x é +0 e y é -0, return true.
    Se x é -0 e y é +0, retorna true.
    Retorna false.
Se Type(x) é String, retorna true se x e y são exatamente a mesma sequência de caracteres (mesmo tamanho e mesmos caracteres nas posições correspondentes); caso contrário, retorna false.
Se Type(x) é Boolean, retorna true se x e y são ambos true ou ambos false; caso contrário, retorna false.
Retorna true se x e y referem-se ao mesmo objeto. Caso contrário, retorna false.
```

Comment: @Marconi Uma vez que ele tenha testado que os tipos de `x` e `y` são iguais (passou do primeiro teste), dois objetos do tipo `Undefined` ou `Null` são considerados iguais. Ou seja, `undefined === undefined` e `null === null`.

Comment: Obrigado @Augusto, pra mim essa é a melhor resposta, já deixei o meu +1!

Answer (score 31):

Em JavaScript existem dois pares de operadores de igualdade: `===` e `!==`, e os gêmeos do mal (evil twins) `==` e `!=`, conforme descrito em *JavaScript: The Good Parts* por Douglas Crockford.

### `===` e `!==`

O primeiro par de operadores, `===` e `!==`, funciona como o `==` e `!==` na maioria das linguagens de programação. Então se os valores comparados com `===` possuem o mesmo valor e são do mesmo tipo, a expressão resultará em `true`, já o `!==` indica o oposto a essa afirmação.

#### Exemplos utilizando `===` e `!==`

```javascript
2 === 2             // true
'ola' === 'ola'     // true
'' === '0'          // false
0 === ''            // false
0 === '0'           // false
false === 'false'   // false
false === '0'       // false
false === undefined // false
false === null      // false
null === undefined  // false
' \t\r\n ' === 0    // false
```

### `==` e `!=`

Já o segundo par de operadores, `==` e `!=`, funcionam da seguinte forma. Quando os ambos os valores comparados são do mesmo tipo, os gêmeos do mal se comportam como o outro par de operadores (`===` e `!==`), mas quando os valores comparados são de tipos diferentes, eles tentam corrigir os valores através de uma conversão antes de fazer a comparação. Isso parece legal, mas pode gerar resultados difíceis de entender e dificulta a manutenção do código.

#### Exemplos utilizando `==` e `!=`

```javascript
2 == 2             // true
'ola' == 'ola'     // true
'' == '0'          // false
0 == ''            // true
0 == '0'           // true
false == 'false'   // false
false == '0'       // true
false == undefined // false
false == null      // false
null == undefined  // true
' \t\r\n ' == 0    // true
```

Uma recomendação dada por Douglas Crockford é nunca utilizar os gêmeos do mal, no lugar deles sempre utilize `===` e `!==`.

Answer (score 28):

O JavaScript possui conversão automática de tipos, segundo [algumas regras não muito intuitivas](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3). O operador `==` usa essa conversão nas duas pontas da comparação. Já `===` exige que os dois termos da comparação sejam do mesmo tipo, além de terem o mesmo valor.

Dessa maneira, por exemplo:

```
"1" == 1; // true, mesmo com tipos diferentes
"1" === 1; // false, justamente devido aos tipos diferentes
```

Answer (score 20):

Normalmente linguagens fracamente tipadas se encarregam de fazer a conversão dos tipos de dados.

Sendo assim, quando você utiliza o operador `==`, a linguagem faz o `cast` ou conversão de tipos para comparação dos valores.

Já o operador `===` diz para comparar os tipos de dados e valores que estão sendo testados.

Answer (score 20):

Quando você usa o operador `==` e os tipos são diferentes, internamente o Javascript faz uma conversão para números. No caso, `false` quando convertido para número transforma-se em `0`.
No caso do operador `===`, os dois argumentos devem ser exatamente iguais, em tipo e valor, por isso o resultado é falso.

Answer (score 18):

JavaScript tem ambas as comparações *estritas* e *abstratas*.

Uma comparação *estrita* (`===`) só é verdade se os operandos são do mesmo tipo e possuem o mesmo valor.

A comparação mais usada é a *abstrata* (`==`), que converte os operandos para o mesmo tipo antes de fazer a comparação.

`Strings` são comparados com base na ordenação lexicográfica, usando valores Unicode.

Answer (score 16):

O operador `==` converte entre tipos para verificar.

Um exemplo é que `true==1` e que `false==''` vão dar ambos true, apesar de serem comparações de tipos de dados diferentes.

Utilizando o operador `===`, está a se "forçar" um tipo de dados, tal como `true===1` e `false===''` dão ambos `false`.

Aviso: `NaN` é um objecto em javascript.
Isto significa que `{}=={}` vai ser falso, tal como `NaN==NaN`.

O site da MDN (Mozilla Development Network) utiliza este 'truque' para detectar `NaN`.

Uma maneira de verificar se é um número pode ser assim: `valor+0==valor+0`. Se valor não for numero, resulta em `false`.

Comment: Por favor, adicione a referência da documentação do MDN.

Answer (score 15):

O problema do Javascript é que ele tem tipagem fraca, ou seja, faz conversões implícitas de tipo. Uma comparação `'0' == 0`resulta `true` porque o operador converte string para número, na tentativa de "consertar" a diferença de tipos.

O PHP tem o mesmo problema. Imagino que devido às origens na Web, JS e PHP optaram por tipagem fraca porque todo dado vindo de e.g. um formulário da Web é string, mas muitos campos "significam" números.

Já o Python tem tipagem forte (embora dinâmica) e comparação entre tipos diferentes resulta, via de regra, em Falso.

Os operadores `===` e `!==` fazem comparação "forte", ou seja, segundo as regras de tipagem forte, e retornam Falso para comparação entre strings e números.

Answer (score 9):

O `===` compara variáveis do mesmo tipo.
O `==` segue regras como "true" `==` true, 1 `==` true, etc..

Portanto, utilize "use strict" no início da sua função ou arquivo, isso força a utilização de `===`.

Comment: Não, o "use strict" nao serve para isto. Ele serve para gerar erro ao tentar usar uma variável não declarada.