# Javascript tem um operador xor?

Tags: javascript

Existe um operador xor em javascript e qual seria a forma 'simbólica' dele (por exemplo or tem || e and tem &&)?

Comment: `!!(true ^ false)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O JavaScript não possui um operador XOR lógico.

Tem um operador XOR bit a bit ^ que pode realizar uma comparação bit a bit de dois números, mas isso não ajuda quando você deseja obter o resultado de uma XOR de duas expressões, que não retornam um número.

O que você pode fazer é criar uma função para fazer este tipo de operação lógica:

```
function myXOR(x, y) {
  return (x || y) && !(x && y);
}


if (myXOR(hasValue(value1), hasValue(value2))) {
  //FAZ ALGUMA COISA
}
```

Seguem algumas referências para você entender melhor como funciona as operações lógicas no JS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operadores_bit_a_bit

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/xor.html

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/bitwise-xor-operator-decrement-hat-javascript

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar o operador `^` como descrito [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4540481/5325043) resposta

Ex.:

```
var nb = 5^9 // = 12
```

Para valores booleanos você pode converter com `!!`, que irá inverter o resultado transformando-o em `boolean`, depois invertendo-o novamente

Ex.:

```
!!(false ^ true)
```

Answer (score 4):

Se você analisar a [tabela verdade do XOR](https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Porta_XOR&oldid=53925323), também conhecido como "Ou exclusivo", verá que a saída é verdade apenas quando as entradas são diferentes.

```
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────┐
│ entrada_a │ entrada_b │ saida │
├───────────┼───────────┼───────┤
│ false     │ false     │ false │
│ false     │ true      │ true  │
│ true      │ false     │ true  │
│ true      │ true      │ false │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────┘
```

Dito isso, é bem simples implementar um `xor` correspondente à tabela acima, pois o resultado é verdadeiro apenas se as entradas são diferentes. Basta retorna `entrada_a != entrada_b`.

```
function xor(a, b) {
    return a !== b;
}
```

<sup>Estou usando comparação estrita, mas você deve usar dependendo da sua necessidade, entenda a diferença em "[Qual a diferença entre os operadores == e === em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7/6333)".</sup>

---

Lembrando que o operador XOR possui [comutatividade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comutatividade), ou seja:

```
(a ^ b) ^ c == a ^ (b ^ c)
```

Usando operador `!=` como um `xor` mantém a [comutatividade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comutatividade), veja exemplos:

```
(0 ^ 1) ^ 1; // 1
0 ^ (1 ^ 1); // 1

(0 !== 1) !== 1; // true
0 !== (1 !== 1); // true
```

Comment: Bom, não exatamente... se passar `xor(null, undefined)` ou `(4, 2)` ele retorna `true`, o que está errado. Uma implementação melhor seria `function xor(a, b) { return !!a !== !!b }`. O valor booleano tem que ser diferente, não o valor real.

Comment: Mas aí entra validação de inputs que não é o escopo da resposta (a tabela verdade mostra que os inputs válidos são apenas `true` e `false`). Você está usando como exemplo que `null` e `undefined` seriam valores válidos para a função. Essas peculiaridades específicas do seu caso devem ser ajustadas de acordo com a necessidade. Para demonstração de conceito, acredito que adicionar esta informação seria desnecessária na resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Olha, pra não ter que converter para booleano, você pode "improvisar" um XOR usando AND e if/else. Segue aí um trecho de código, usando duas variáveis p e q.

```js
var p = false
var q = true

p = window.confirm("Selecione 'OK' para p==true, e 'Cancelar' para p==false.")
q = window.confirm("Selecione 'OK' para q==true, e 'Cancelar' para q==false.")

if (!p && q){
  window.alert ("A expressão é verdadeira.")
}else{
  if (!q && p){
    window.alert ("A expressão é verdadeira.")
  }else{
    window.alert ("A expressão é falsa.")
  }
}
```