# Comparação em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

bom quero saber se minha comparação tem como ser melhorada, quero deixar o código mais curto (enxuto)

```js
const teste = function(a){
   if(a != null && a != undefined && a != ""){
        console.log('e diferente')
    }else{
        console.log(`o valor que vc passou e ${a}`)
    }
}

teste()
```

Sobre a parte `if(a != null && a != undefined && a != "")`, como posso deixá-la mais curta?

Answer (score 5):

Pode fazer apenas:

```
if(a){
   ...
}else{
   ...
}
```

`a` teria que ser diferente de *null*, *undefined* e *vazio*. Exatamente as 3 condições que você colocou no seu código, acrescentando que também não pode ser o número `0` (`teste(0)`). Se quiser permitir `0`, teria que fazer:

```
if(a || a === 0){
```

Teste:

```js
const teste = function(a){
   if(a){
        console.log('e diferente')
    }else{
        console.log(`o valor que vc passou e ${a}`)
    }
}

teste() // else
teste(' ') // if
teste(0) // else
teste('0') // if
teste('') // else
```

Answer (score 5):

Também podes fazer assim:

```js
const teste = function(a) { a ? console.log(`O valor que vc passou é ${a}`) : console.log('Nenhum valor informado') };

teste('Teste');
teste('');
teste(null);
teste(undefined);
```

Ou utilizar [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
const teste = a => a ? console.log(`O valor que vc passou é ${a}`) : console.log('Nenhum valor informado');

teste('Teste');
teste('');
teste(null);
teste(undefined);
```

Comment: o código poderia ficar ainda mais legível, pois uma função arrow com somente um parâmetro nao precisa de **( )**, ficaria... const teste = a => a ?...

Comment: Sim, mas levando em consideração a sua pergunta: *a parte **if(a != null && a != undefined && a != "")** como posso deixa-la mais curta ?* ... Esse não era o foco ao responder.

Comment: Arrow funtion não são compatíveis com um par navegadores

Answer (score 4):

As outras respostas sugerem uma verificação por valores [falsey](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/271721), o que exclui mais coisa do que a sua condição.

Sem alterar o sentido do seu código original, você pode simplesmente remover a primeira ou a segunda condição. Elas são idênticas porque você não está usando [comparação de igualdade estrita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-os-operadores-e-em-javascript). Então, se o objetivo do código é ficar menor, pode usar simplesmente:

```
if (a != null && a != "")
```

Se a sua intenção com `a != ""` for de excluir somente strings vazias, utilize o comparador igualdade estrita `===`:

```
if (a != null && a !== "")
```

Caso contrário, também vai proibir valores que retornam `''` quando *convertidos* para strings – como arrays vazias, por exemplo.