# JavaScript: O resultado é exibido mesmo sem ter dados inseridos pelo usuário!

Tags: javascript

Bem, a ideia era a seguinte: fazer uma simples função que calculasse o valor inserido em um input e retornar-se o resultado para o usuário, porém se o valor inserido for zero, a mensagem que retorna é: "Valor em branco!"; (Porque o " " ao ser convertido para número passa a ser igual a zero). Resumindo, existe uma forma disso aí funcionar ou eu vou ter que rescrever de uma outra forma.

```
function inp() {

    var num = Number(input.value);
    var myNum = (num == " ");

    if (Number.isNaN(num) == true) {
        alert("Formato Inválido!");
    } else if (myNum === true) {
        alert("Valor em branco!")
    } else {
        alert((50 + 50 + 50) * num);
    }
}
```

Comment: **`num === " "`**

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre os operadores == e === em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7/18246)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar um ternário para definir `num`:

```js
function inp() {

    var input = document.querySelector("#ip");
    var num = input.value == '0' ? '0' : Number(input.value);
    var myNum = (num == " ");

    if (Number.isNaN(num) == true) {
        alert("Formato Inválido!");
    } else if (myNum === true) {
        alert("Valor em branco!")
    } else {
        alert((50 + 50 + 50) * num);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ip" />
<input type="button" value="ok" onclick="inp()" />
```

Comment: Pô, valeu mesmo! Sou novo na plataforma portanto não posso votar como útil, mas você é f*.

Comment: Pode marcar como certa

Comment: Abaixo das setas existe um símbolo "✓"... mas vc só pode marcar isso em 1 resposta, a que vc prefere (a que te ajudou mais, achou melhor, amais correta pra vc etc...)