# Existe benefício de desempenho em substituir o operador "==" pelo operador "==="?

Tags: javascript, operadores

Estou usando o [JSLint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSLint) para verificar se o código-fonte JavaScript está em conformidade com as regras de codificação, e ele está retornando muitas sugestões para substituir `==` (dois sinais de igual) com `===` (três sinais de igual) ao fazer coisas como comparar `idlol.value.length == 0` dentro de um condicional `if`.

Existe um benefício de desempenho em substituir `==` por `===` ?

Se nenhuma conversão de tipo ocorrer, haverá um ganho de desempenho em relação a `==` ?

Comment: Não lembro de nenhuma e duvido que o JSLint vá fazer alguma sugestão por questão de performance, ainda mais de uma micro micro-otimização. Veja mais em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7/qual-a-diferença-entre-os-operadores-e-em-javascript

Comment: É que não lembro agora, mas vi uma página que faz um benchmark desses operadores, e o `==` fica à frente do `===`.

Comment: @dvd, essa pergunta existe nos brothers mas não achei as repostas claras o suficiente, mesmo porque meu inglês is bad. Veja no site dos brothers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: Já tinha visto. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fiz um pequeno teste no Node.js v9.8.0:

```
"use strict";
let t0, t1, dummy;

t0 = (new Date()).getTime();
dummy = true;
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    let j = "" + i;
    let k = 0 + i;
    dummy = dummy || (i == k);
}
t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
console.log("" + (t1 - t0) + "ms " + dummy);

t0 = (new Date()).getTime();
dummy = true;
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    let j = "" + i;
    let k = 0 + i;
    dummy = dummy || (i === k);
}
t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
console.log("" + (t1 - t0) + "ms " + dummy);

t0 = (new Date()).getTime();
dummy = true;
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    let j = "" + i;
    let k = 0 + i;
    dummy = dummy || (i == j);
}
t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
console.log("" + (t1 - t0) + "ms " + dummy);

t0 = (new Date()).getTime();
dummy = true;
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    let j = "" + i;
    let k = 0 + i;
    dummy = dummy || (i === j);
}
t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
console.log("" + (t1 - t0) + "ms " + dummy);
```

O maior tempo é consumido pela criação da string j. Os resultados na minha máquina foram os seguintes:

```
883ms # int == int verdadeiro
1006ms # int === int verdadeiro
1030ms # int == string verdadeiro
1016ms # int === string falso
```

Surpreendentemente, o operador == foi mais rápido que o ===, mas apenas quando os dois objetos sendo comparados já são do mesmo tipo. Mas é uma diferença minúscula (12ns por comparação). Os valores devem ser diferentes num browser ou em versões diferentes do Node.js.

Comment: Essa diferença faz sentido ja que o operador `===`, além de verificar o valor, também verifica o tipo das variáveis

Comment: Eu esperava === fosse mais rápido porque verificar o tipo é mais rápido que o valor, mas enfim, vivendo e aprendendo :)

Comment: Pela natureza e especificação de cada um dos operadores, `===` tende a ser mais rápido, é inegável. Se for comparação de mesmo tipo, eles têm os mesmos exatos passos no algoritmo de comparação. O seu teste precisa de mais amostras, cada teste dura só 1 segundo. Não pode ser tido como um teste estastístico confiável e estável. Eu mesmo rodei aqui várias vezes e cada vez deram resultados divergentes.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Não faz sentido não, é bem pelo contrário. O algoritmo de `===` está contido no de `==`. Uma string "6" é armazenado com valor diferente do um número 6. Não há como comparar valor sem verificar seu tipo primeiro, e é o que o algoritmo `==` precisa fazer em seus passos adicionais caso os dois objetos não sejam do mesmo tipo, ele converte o objeto a *comparar* para o mesmo do tipo do *comparado* para fazer a verificação.

Comment: Apenas reforçando a declaração do @AndreFigueiredo: segue os respectivos algoritmos [Algoritmo de Igualdade Abstrata (a.k.a ==)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) e o [Algoritmo de Igualdade Rigorosa (a.k.a ===)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6)

Comment: Removendo o "let j..." inútil dos dois primeiros testes, o === fica msis rápido (25ms x 20ms). A otimização da operação deve mudar. Por outro lado, remover o "let k..." dos dois últimos testes alarga a diferença em favor do ==.  Realmente não dá pra confiar muito nos números.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que esteja se referindo a regra [eqeqeq](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq).

O motivo para esta regra, não é devido a qual quer ganho de desempenho, mas sim para melhorar a coesão, afinal o [Algoritmo de Igualdade Abstrata](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) é bastante obscuro, para se ter uma ideia, as seguintes comparações retornam `true`:

```
[] == false
[] == ![]
3 == "03"
```

Em todo caso, você pode pode criar algumas exceções para esta regra, como por exemplo comparações com `null` ou entre `literais`

**smart - comparação entre literais**

```
/*eslint eqeqeq: ["error", "smart"]*/

typeof foo == 'undefined'
'hello' != 'world'
0 == 0
true == true
foo == null
```

**always, except null - comparação com nulo**

```
/*eslint eqeqeq: ["error", "always", {"null": "ignore"}]*/

foo == null
```