# Como colocar um array como parâmetro de uma função em js?

Tags: javascript

Preciso escrever uma função que recebe dois parâmetros, sendo que o primeiro eh um array de números e o segundo um número qualquer.

A função precisa verificar se o segundo parâmetro (que pode ser qualquer número) está contido no array (primeiro parâmetro)

pensei no seguinte código em javascript:

```
function contem(array,y){

  var array = []; 

### tentei fazer o programa ler o primeiro parâmetro como um array(ñ funcionou)

  for(i = 0; i < array.lenght; i++){

    if (i == y){

      return true
    }

    else {

      return false 
    }
  }
}
```

explicação do código / dúvidas:

- Como faço para q a função entenda que o primeiro parâmetro eh um array?
- Pensei em declarar uma variável e dizer que eh igual a um array vazio, mas não está funcionando.

  - A minha ideia eh criar um loop for q varre o array e se encontra o y (segundo parâmetro) retorna true, caso contrario (else) retorna false.

obs.: se tiver alguma coisa q possa ler também eh válido, esse exercício faz parte de um desafio online, estou há umas 10 horas tentando fazer e nda ....

Answer (score 1):

Alguns pontos:

- A propriedade se chama `length`, não `lenght`.
- Você está comparando o valor do índice ao invés do valor do conteúdo em uma determinada posição, `i == y` é diferente de `array[i] == y` (se possível, use `===` ao invés de `==`, a diferença desses operadores podem ser vistas [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7/4808)).
- Na primeira iteração (quando o índice ainda é 0), sua função já está retornando um booleano para qualquer condicional do valor existir ou não no *array*. O retorno falso, deveria estar fora do loop. Uma vez que, ao iterar sob todo o array e o valor não esteja presente, deve-se retornar `false`.
- Sua função possui um parâmetro de nome `array` e logo em seguida você declara uma variável com o mesmo nome `var array = [];`.
- Embora funcione nesse caso, você não está declarando a variável `i` no loop: `for(i = 0; i < array.lenght; i++)`. O correto é utilizar [`var`, `let` ou `const`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/206117/4808), de acordo com a sua necessidade.

```js
// Editando pouca coisa no código da pergunta
function contem(array,y){
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (array[i] == y){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(contem(array, 2))
console.log(contem(array, 4))
console.log(contem(array, 6))
```

Tem pontos que ainda podem ser melhorados, mas acredito ser discussão para outra questão, outro momento.

Comment: O correto é `if(array[i] == y)`.

Comment: @v.Santos thanks, corrigido.

Answer (score 0):

Para saber se uma variável é um array, você pode tanto utilizar o operator `instanceof` ou a função `Array.isArray()`. Confira-se:

```
var numero = 1;
var numeros = [5, 7, 42];

numeros instanceof Array;
Array.isArray(numeros);
//Em ambos os casos retorna true

numero instanceof Array;
Array.isArray(numero);
//Em ambos os casos retorna false
```

Agora, no seu caso específico, você precisa se certificar de que o primeiro argumento é um array? Bem, isso definitivamente não me parece necessário. É só fazer sua função sem aquela declaração `var array = [];` e mais algumas correções e as coisas vão funcionar. Confira-se:

```
function contem(array,y){

  for(i = 0; i < array.lenght; i++){

    if (array[i] == y) return true;
     //corrigi a condição no interior do if e retirei o else return false de dentro do loop.
    }
  return false; 
}
```

O curioso é que o javascript já tem uma função que verifica se um elemento está dentro de um array. Isso permite uma solução mais curta por meio de um wrapper. Veja:

```
function contem(arr, y){
  return arr.includes(y);
}
```

E, por fim, eu tive a ideia de resolver o problema recursivamente da forma mais curta possível. Eu acho que você não vai entender patavinas, mesmo assim, deixo a solução a título de curiosidade e para um pessoalzinho em estágio um pouco mais avançado. Cf:

```
function contem(arr, y, i=0){
  return arr[i] == y || (i < arr.length 
    && contem(arr, y, ++i));
}

var numeros = [5, 7, 42];

console.log(contem(numeros, 42));
console.log(contem(numeros, 28));
```

Comment: só faltou declarar o i como variável lá em cima dentro do loop for. muito obrigado pela ajuda :)