# Função InnerHTML não funciona?

Tags: javascript, dom, handlebars.js

Estou utilizando a view engine handlebars, porém, quando fui manipular elementos DOM, ele continua com o valor dado a ele pelo escape, segue o código abaixo:

> **página monitor.handlebars:**

```
<script src="/monitoramento.js"></script>
{{#each result}}
<div class="container mt-5">
    <h6>Bomba 1: <small id="bomba1">{{bomba}}</small></h6>
    <hr>
    <h6>Bomba 2: <small id="bomba2">texto aqui</small></h6>
    <hr>
    <h6>Caixa D'Água: <small id="caixa">texto aqui</small></h6>
    <hr>
    <h6>Cisterna: <small id="cisterna">texto aqui</small></h6>
    <hr>
    <h6>Temperatura: <small id="temperatura">texto aqui</small></h6>
    <hr>
    <h6>Pressão: <small id="pressao">texto aqui</small></h6>
    <hr>
    <h6>Data: <small id="data">texto aqui</small></h6>
    <hr>
</div>
{{else}}
    <h1>Não foram encontrados registros!</h1>
{{/each}}
```

> **Pequeno script monitoramento.js para manipular elementos do DOM:**

```
var bomba1 = document.querySelector('#bomba1')

if (bomba1.value = 1) {
    bomba1.innerHTML = 'Bomba ligada'
}
```

porquê não funciona?

OBS: No arquivo da raiz do projeto eu coloquei o caminho para os conteúdos estáticos.

Comment: No `if` vc está usando um operador errado em `bomba1.value = 1`, quando deveria ser `==` ou `===`. Veja [neste tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7/8063) a diferença entre eles.

Comment: Seu _if_ está atribuindo '1' ao invés de comparar se _value_ é igual a '1'. Utilize o operador **'=='**  ou então o operador igual estrito **'==='**.

Comment: caraca nem percebi esse erro que fiz vou implementar aqui e já dou a resposta...

Comment: Eu tentei implementar aqui, porém continua dando o mesmo resultado, ele não substitui o elemento :/

Comment: Olha no console possíveis erros.

Comment: no console do navegador apresenta o seguinte erro: monitoramento.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

não sei porque mas ta dando valor "nulo"

Comment: Você parece que não estabeleceu o VALUE para o elemento com id "bomba1". Tenta por um VALUE nele, que acho que o seu IF funcionará.

Comment: É porque vc está carregando o arquivo de monitoramento antes dos elementos. Quando tenta executar a linha `var bomba1 = document.querySelector('#bomba1')` o elemento `#bomba1` ainda não existe.

Comment: eu importei o script abaixo de todo o código e estabeleci o VALUE para a variável bomba1, mesmo assim não funcionou eu deixei a variável assim: `var bomba1 = document.querySelector('#bomba1').value`

Comment: no `if` eu deixei assim: `if (bomba1.value == 1) {
    bomba1.innerHTML = 'Bomba ligada'
}`

Comment: @Teuuz1994 você fez o `compile` no Handlebars?

Comment: não eu uso o handlebars a pouco tempo, até olhei na documentação mas não compreendi muito bem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente, o que está impedindo o seu código de funcionar é porque você não está utilizando o método `compile` do Handlebars. Então a solução é simples:

Primeiramente, procure trazer seus arquivos de `<script>` sempre ao final do corpo do seu HTML. Depois, o que eu fiz foi atribuir a uma variável `template` o método `compile` da biblioteca, como é informado na documentação:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile("{{result}}");
```

Então o seu código ficaria assim:

```
    var template = Handlebars.compile("{{result}}");

    var bomba1 = document.querySelector('#bomba1')

    if (bomba1.value = 1) {
        bomba1.innerHTML = "Bomba ligada";
    }
```

Se quiser mais informações, dá uma olhadinha na documentação da biblioteca Handlebars: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#what-is-handlebars

Espero ter ajudado, abraços!

Comment: ok vou implementar aqui e já falo a resposta, mesmo assim valeu mesmo amigo

Comment: fiz de tudo mas aqui não funcionou, e não sei o porque no meu console do navegador aparece que esse `Handlebars` não foi definido: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined`

Comment: consegui! valeu a todos que puderam tirar um pouco do seu tempo para me ajudar funcionou aqui não estava funcionando porque eu tinha esquecido de importar o handlebars para o corpo da página com um script

Comment: Isso ai! Se tiver mais alguma dúvida, só chamar :D