# Como excluir um elemento do array caso já exista um valor igual?

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Estou tentando armazenar o ID de algumas contas que foram selecionadas por um checkbox, ou seja eu terei um array com todas contas que estão selecionadas, mas eu preciso que quando ela for desmarcada, exclua o id dela do array, eu tentei fazer um filtro com map na array porem não me retornada nada, nem o console log que coloquei para testar.

```js
const [contasSelected, setSelected] = useState([])

function cSelect(e) {
  contasSelected.map(a => {
    if (a.ID = e) {
      console.log('o ID', a.ID, 'já está marcado')
    } else {

      setSelected([...contasSelected, {
        ID: e
      }])
      console.log(contasSelected)
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<tbody className='Table-Contas-Body'>
  {Contas.map( e =>(
  <tr key={ e.ID}>
    <FormCheck id={ e.ID} type="checkbox" onChange={ ()=> cSelect(e.ID)}/> // aqui é onde passo o ID da conta para a função 
      <td>{e.ID}</td>
      <td>{e.Cliente}</td>
      <td>{e.Valor}</td>
      <td>{e.DataEmissao}</td>
      <td>{e.DataVencimento}</td>
      <td>{e.Historico}</td>
  </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

1º erro: você esta tentando executar `if (a.ID = e)`. Porém em uma comparação você deve usar `==` ou `===`. Veja em [Qual a diferença entre os operadores == e === em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-os-operadores-e-em-javascript)

2º erro: a lógica que você esta tentando aplicar não faz sentido. O map vai percorrer todos os elementos do array, um por um. E do jeito que está escrito o array sempre estará vazio, afinal você esta tentando incluir um elemento nele somente dentro do map.

Solução:

Você pode usar o método [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) para ver se existe e qual o index do elemento que está procurando.

- Caso não exista: inclua o elemento no array.
- Caso já exista: exclua o elemento. Para fazer isso você pode criar um array que é uma cópia do estado `contasSelected`, usar o médoto [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) para remover o elemento desejado e depois: `setSelected(novoArrayQueVoceCriou)`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu vou analisar meu código novamente e fazer com o findindex.